# Page Load vs Fancy Design

Tags: user-centered-design, loading

The more complex/fancy looking a website is the greater the page load - we know this.

My question is, does a slow website have more of a detrimental effect to the experience of a user then a hard to use, plain website?

I suspect a balance between the two is the ideal but I have come across a case where in order to make the user experience better the website will suffer slow load times. If anyone could point me in the direction a of study around page load frustrations that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The actual page speed doesn't really matter. It's the perceived page speed. In eCommerce there is a lot of research done in page load. I've seen assessments of 20% to 60% decrease in conversion when 1s more load speed is being introduced.

There really are a lot of people that have done research on it, varying quite a bit. But everyone seems to agree that increasing the perceived load speed is bad for business and UX. I suggest a google search to "Page load vs conversion" or something similar.

This article provides a good jumping off point, with lots of links to other articles and studies - https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/your-website-design-should-load-in-4-seconds/

Comment: Thanks for the link, couldn't really find a good one with multiple sources quickly :)